# Application Storage Location on Android Device

Tags: android

I have installed one `Sample` application onto the Android device. My installed application is stored where on my Adroid device (my application is not authorized in the google-play ), but i can see the other application storage location path (these applications are authorized to google-play ).
Thanks.
 For example, I installed one `Calculator` application. It will be stored to `/data/calculaot-package-name` in the device. For testing purposes I installed my own application to the Android device. Its path I have not seen in my application's stored path.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but your explanation of the problem is not even close to `clear`.

Comment: please explain clearly to understand quickly, then only we can give a proper solution

Comment: elaborate your answer.As whatever  you want to say is not clear...

Comment: Sorry. For example i installed one authorized (google-play) application into the android device. In this application is stored to /data/package. But i installed one sample application. It's my own application. It's can be located where in android device..

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with API Level 8, you can allow your application to be installed on the external storage (for example, the device's SD card). This is an optional feature you can declare for your application with the [android:installLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) manifest attribute. If you do not declare this attribute, your application will be installed on the internal storage only and it cannot be moved to the external storage.

To allow the system to install your application on the external storage, modify your manifest file to include the [android:installLocation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install) attribute in the  element, with a value of either "preferExternal" or "auto". For example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

If you declare "preferExternal", you request that your application be installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee that your application will be installed on the external storage. If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

If you declare "auto", you indicate that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. The system will decide where to install your application based on several factors. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

When your application is installed on the external storage:

- There is no effect on the application performance so long as the external storage is mounted on the device.
- The .apk file is saved on the external storage, but all private user data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are saved on the internal device memory.
- The unique container in which your application is stored is encrypted with a randomly generated key that can be decrypted only by the device that originally installed it. Thus, an application installed on an SD card works for only one device.
- The user can move your application to the internal storage through the system settings.

**Warning:** When the user enables USB mass storage to share files with a computer or unmounts the SD card via the system settings, the external storage is unmounted from the device and all applications running on the external storage are immediately killed.

Details: [All Installation Location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether or not the application is installed to internal or external memory. If you use (in your manifest) the `android:installLocation` of `preferExternal` or `auto` it is probable/possible that it is stored in the `.android_secure` portion of the sdcard. Otherwise, it should be located at `/data/app/com.yourpackage`.

If it is stored in the secure area, you won't be able to get at it (assuming you aren't doing hacky things - even then I am not sure if you can get at it).

Edit: I should add that in most cases you can move apps to internal storage from the application manager. If this is your app though you can specify that you want it on internal storage only.

Answer (score 0):

To find out manually, adb pull /data/system/packages.xml and examine it to find the code path entry.

To do it from a program, there is an api call for determining the code path which you can find in the docs.

What use you can make of the knowledge may vary from case to case and version to version.